# How to maintain position of output panel on VF page

Tags: visualforce

Hi I am having a pageblock table which on certain criteria renders. Along with is a output panel which is shown all the time. Attaching image for reference. The correct position of command link and combobox is in IMAGE 2. But before the table renders the position of output panel is not correct. Once it renders it comes to its proper location. Can someone share some thoughts here ? Ex code for reference:IMAGE 1 - [image]

IMAGE 2 - [image]

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!xyz}" var="t" id="abc" rendered="{!showTable}">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputField value="{!t.xyz__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        <apex:outputPanel >

            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!rows}">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            </apex:selectList>&nbsp;
            <apex:commandLink action="{!addRow}" reRender="teamMemberSection">Add team members</apex:commandLink>

        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: We seem to be missing some code... can you give us more context?